# Problema para fazer para enviar um type complex Soap

Tags: android, web-service, ksoap2

Estou fazendo um método para atualizar dados do cadastro do cliente, mas quando passo por esse método estou com problemas para enviar o objeto, alguém já viu esse problema?

*Segue o código:*

```
package routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante.routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante.models;

public class DadosCadastraisSeralizable implements KvmSerializable{

     public int codigo;
     public String usuario;
     public  String senha;
     public String cep;
     public String bairro;
     public String endereco;
     public String numero;
     public String complemento;
     public String foneComercial;
     public String foneResidencial;
     public String foneCelular;
     public String email;

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int i) {
        switch (i){
                case 0:
                     return this.codigo;
                case 1:
                     return this.usuario;
                case 2:
                    return this.senha;
                case 3:
                    return this.cep;
                case 4:
                     return this.bairro;
                case 5:
                     return this.endereco;
                case 6:
                    return this.numero;
                case 7:
                    return this.complemento;
                case 8:
                     return this.foneComercial;
                case 9:
                     return this.foneResidencial;
                case 10:
                     return this.foneCelular;
                case 11:
                    return this.email;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
        return 12;
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int i, Object o) {
          switch (i){
              case 0:
                  this.codigo= Integer.parseInt(o.toString());
                  break;
              case 1:
                   this.usuario=o.toString();
                  break;
              case 2:
                   this.senha=o.toString();
                  break;
              case 3:
                   this.cep=o.toString();
                  break;
              case 4:
                  this.bairro=o.toString();
                  break;
              case 5:
                   this.endereco= o.toString();
                  break;
              case 6:
                  this.numero= o.toString();
                  break;
              case 7:
                   this.complemento= o.toString();
                  break;
              case 8:
                   this.foneComercial= o.toString();
                  break;
              case 9:
                   this.foneResidencial=o.toString();
                  break;
              case 10:
                  this.foneCelular=o.toString();
                  break;
              case 11:
                  this.email=o.toString();
                  break;
          }
    }

    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int i, Hashtable hashtable, PropertyInfo propertyInfo) {
        switch (i){
            case 0:
                 propertyInfo.type=PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
                 propertyInfo.name="CodigoCliente";
                break;
            case 1:
                 propertyInfo.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                 propertyInfo.name="Usuario";
                break;
            case 2:
                propertyInfo.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                propertyInfo.name="Senha";
                break;
            case 3:
                propertyInfo.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                propertyInfo.name="CEP";
                break;
            case 4:
                propertyInfo.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                propertyInfo.name="Bairro";
                break;
            case 5:
                propertyInfo.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                propertyInfo.name="Endereco";
                break;
            case 6:
                propertyInfo.type= PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                propertyInfo.name="Numero";
                break;
            case 7:
                propertyInfo.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                propertyInfo.name="Complemento";
                break;
            case 8:
                propertyInfo.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                propertyInfo.name="TelComercial";
                break;
            case 9:
                 propertyInfo.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                propertyInfo.name="TelResidencial";
                break;
            case 10:
                 propertyInfo.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                 propertyInfo.name="TelCelular";
                break;
            case 11:
                propertyInfo.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                propertyInfo.name="Email";
        }

    }
}
```

*Esse é o método na classe webservice:*

```
  public String atuzalizarCadastroCliente(DadosCadastraisSeralizable dados) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("urn:RouterBoxMobile", "AtualizarCadastroClientes");



        SoapObject chaveIntegracao = new  SoapObject("urn:RouterBoxMobile", "AtualizarCadastroClientes");
        chaveIntegracao.addProperty("ChaveIntegracao",chaveDeIntegracao);

        request.addProperty("Autenticacao", chaveIntegracao);
        request.addProperty("DadosAtualizadosClientes",dados);


        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        envelope.implicitTypes=true;

         httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL_WEBSERVICE);
         httpTransportSE.debug=true;

         httpTransportSE.call("",envelope);

        SoapObject  response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        //resposta=envelope.getResponse();

        return response.toString();


    }
```

*Erro:*

```
11-07 10:58:48.162 25214-25214/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-07 10:58:49.702 25214-25214/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-07 10:58:49.994 25214-25214/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-07 10:58:51.850 25214-25214/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante W/System.err: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG (empty) <br>@1:7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@52bfd5d4) 
11-07 10:58:51.850 25214-25214/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(KXmlParser.java:2046)
11-07 10:58:51.850 25214-25214/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:127)
11-07 10:58:51.850 25214-25214/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:96)
11-07 10:58:51.850 25214-25214/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:189)
11-07 10:58:51.850 25214-25214/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
11-07 10:58:51.850 25214-25214/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante W/System.err:     at routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante.WebService.atuzalizarCadastroCliente(WebService.java:185)
11-07 10:58:51.850 25214-25214/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante W/System.err:     at routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante.DadosCadastrais.onClick(DadosCadastrais.java:161)
11-07 10:58:51.850 25214-25214/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
11-07 10:58:51.850 25214-25214/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
11-07 10:58:51.850 25214-25214/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-07 10:58:51.850 25214-25214/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-07 10:58:51.850 25214-25214/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-07 10:58:51.850 25214-25214/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-07 10:58:51.850 25214-25214/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 10:58:51.850 25214-25214/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-07 10:58:51.850 25214-25214/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-07 10:58:51.850 25214-25214/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-07 10:58:51.850 25214-25214/routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

*Esse é o xml da consulta:*

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:atu="AtualizarCadastroClientes">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <atu:AtualizarCadastroClientes soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <Autenticacao xsi:type="urn:Autenticacao" xmlns:urn="urn:RouterBoxMobile">
            <ChaveIntegracao xsi:type="xsd:string"></ChaveIntegracao>
         </Autenticacao>
         <DadosAtualizadosClientes xsi:type="urn:DadosAtualizadosClientes" xmlns:urn="urn:RouterBoxMobile">
            <!--You may enter the following 12 items in any order-->
            <CodigoCliente xsi:type="xsd:int"></CodigoCliente>
            <Usuario xsi:type="xsd:string">?</Usuario>
            <Senha xsi:type="xsd:string">?</Senha>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <CEP xsi:type="xsd:string">?</CEP>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <Bairro xsi:type="xsd:string">?</Bairro>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <Endereco xsi:type="xsd:string">?</Endereco>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <Numero xsi:type="xsd:int">?</Numero>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <Complemento xsi:type="xsd:string">?</Complemento>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <TelComercial xsi:type="xsd:string">?</TelComercial>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <TelResidencial xsi:type="xsd:string">?</TelResidencial>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <TelCelular xsi:type="xsd:string">?</TelCelular>
            <Email xsi:type="xsd:string">?</Email>
         </DadosAtualizadosClientes>
      </atu:AtualizarCadastroClientes>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```